# Install wowmatrix

Tags: laptop, games

I am trying to install wowmatrix (http://www.wowmatrix.com/)

to manage my wow addons. however when running the .sh file it brings up an install window. but there is no text just blank buttons.

Answer (score 0):

my message before was delete cause was another question like you...but now i have the solution!...googling i found topic in the wowmatrix faq...if you  miss libgtk2.0-0:i386 you cant see the word on the screen

sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386

and i can run wowmatrix...i put a link where i got it

http://www.wowmatrix.com/faq/ubuntu-ia32-libs